# PHP pdf creation and download

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a script that creates pdf document out of a tokens array and downloads it. SO far it does not download it, nor does it put a token per page on in the document. It only reads "tokens"

```
$pdf = new FPDF( ); 
for($i = 0 ; $i < $num_tokens ; $i++){

    $tokens[$i] = pronto_aes_decrypt( $token_crypt[$i] , $prontoKey );

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,$tokens[$i]);


}
unlink("tokens.pdf");
$pdf->Output('tokens.pdf','F');  

readfile('tokens.pdf');

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tokens.pdf"');
```

Comment: What does `pronto_aes_decrypt` do?  Where are `$token_crypt` and `$prontoKey` defined? Do you get any errors (such as permission errors)? Have you tried using full paths?

Comment: Pronto_aes_decrypt is a decryption function and it works properly, both $token_crypt and $prontoKey are defined properly outside. The CSV download version of this script works without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`Output`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) a PDF generated by FPDF for download as follows:

```
$pdf->Output("tokens.pdf","D");
```

Note: You will not be able to output more to the browser window after this, so your `header` calls will not work. That said, you do not need those calls whatsoever, as the above line will output as a file for you and save you the effort of having to manage it on your own.

Comment: This is actually downloaded PDF, so extra data on the page is fine.